# Generating inverse permutation

Tags: r, vector, permutation

Suppose we are given a vector `foo` and we **have to** temporarily permute it (sort or re-order it), compute some vector `bar` on the base of it, and finally permute back both `foo` and `bar` to the original order of `foo` - that means inverse permutation:

```
foo <- c(1, 7, 3, 5, 2)
o <- order(foo)
foo <- foo[o] # Now foo is permuted, and sorted: foo == 1 2 3 5 7
bar = 2 * foo # bar == 2 4 6 10 14
```

And here should go your answer, such that we have the below desired final values:

```
foo == 1 7 3 5 2
bar == 2 14 6 10 4
```

How to do this?

Please simply do not reply: "you could do `bar = 2 * foo` and not permute it". This is just a simple example. In some situations we have to sort `foo` for efficiency (quick search over it) or something like that.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This will work, because `[order(o)]` inverts the action of `[o]`:

```
foo <- c(1, 7, 3, 5, 2)
o <- order(foo)

(foo[o]*2)[order(o)]
# [1]  2 14  6 10  4
```

To show that it works more generally:

```
testAlgorithm <- function(foo) {
    o <- order(foo)
    identical(foo, foo[o][order(o)])
}

x <- c(1, 7, 3, 5, 2)
y <- c(1,2,5,7,4, 99, 88, 3, 0)
z <- sample(1000)                  ## (No ties)
zz <- sample(1000, replace=TRUE)   ## (Many ties)
all(sapply(list(x,y,z,zz), testAlgorithm))
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: The proof goes: 1) `foo[o][order(o)]` is the same as `foo[o[order(o)]]` by associativity of the `[` operator. 2) `o[order(o)]` is the same as `seq_along(o)` . So we have `foo[o][order(o)] <=> foo[o[order(o)]] <=> foo[seq_along(foo)] <=> foo`.

Comment: @flodel -- Yep. It's really just [the associativity of permutation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Product_and_inverse) in another guise.

Answer (score 8):

To recover the original order, use `order(o)`:

```
> (foo[o]*2)[order(o)]
[1]  2 14  6 10  4
```